# HTACCESS: How to block access to all files and folders, but redirect to a certain PHP file in certain case

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've successfully made it impossible for a hacker of my site to access an actual folder (or even to get a 404 message if a non-folder name is typed after the main URL) with this .htaccess listing:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

That's working fine. However, I want it to be the case that *IF* someone adds text ABC after the URL, then the site will redirect to XYZ.PHP. For example:

```
www.mysite.com/abc
```

...redirects to:

```
www.mysite.com/xyz.php
```

(ABC and XYZ are just placeholders for the actual text, obviously.) What is the most efficient way to do this while still retaining all that the .htaccess code above accomplishes?

Comment: Do you need to pass the text "abc" to the.script xyz.php?

Comment: No, I just need to redirect to xyz.php, which is located off the root of the site (where the index.php is located, where the user will be. See my response to Pierre's suggestion below for more info.

Comment: Tom, be sure to select an answer to help guide others who read your question later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^abc$ "/xyz.php" [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

Update: As @bloodyKnuckles noticed it, a `/` was missing.

Comment: This fails both on my local server and on my live site.

I'm using XAMPP for my local server, and let's say the site is called XXX, a folder off of HTDOCS. So to get to it, I simply go to:

    XXX

When I add your RewriteRule as stated and then add "admin" after "XXX/", the URL changes to this:

    XXX/http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/XXX/admin_login.php

Qualifying the initial URL with localhost, like this:

    localhost/xxx

Makes the result after "admin" is added at the end:

    localhost/http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/XXX/admin_login.php

On the live site, it does nothing.

Comment: You may need to add a `RewriteBase /XXX` directive, right after `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. The same results as above occur.

Comment: Yes, as @bloodyKnuckles noticed it, a `/` was missing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a specific RewriteRule before the "catch-all" rule, with a forward slash `/` before the `xyz.php`, works on my setup.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^abc$ /xyz.php [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

Using the forward slash directs apache to look for the substitution path in the web server root directory. (As an added note, the redirect (`R=301`) was caching in my browser, so I resorted to opening a new chrome incognito window each time I made a change.)

Comment: SUCCESS!  Thank you!  It works now, both on my localhost and on the live server.

Comment: Wait...I spoke too soon. This works on Chrome, Opera, IE, and Safari, but not in Firefox. Why would Firefox not respect this directive?

Comment: Wait again, scratch that...Firefox was caching my searches; opening an incognito window solved the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Regex question: What if I want either abc or abc/ to redirec to xyz.php? What is the regular expression I would need to insert within ^abc$ to cover cases of abc or abc/ being issued?

Comment: `^abc/?$` the question mark makes the previous character optional.